# Bootstrap dropdown doesn't work in Codeigniter

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, codeigniter

I just learn Codeigniter, previously I try these code with only bootstrap it's working well but when try to use bootstrap with Codeigniter dropdown menu it doesn't work. Nothing to show when i click at my dropdown menu.

Here is code in head section:

```
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="author" content="">
        <link rel="icon" href="../../favicon.ico">

        <title>Jumbotron Template for Bootstrap</title>

        <link href = "<?php echo base_url(); ?>css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

        <link href = "<?php echo base_url(); ?>css/jumbotron.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

      </head>
      <body>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
          <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
              <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              </button>
              <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Landing Page System</a>
            </div>
            <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
              <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                <li class="dropdown">
              <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                <li class="divider"></li>
                <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                <li class="divider"></li>
                <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
           </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
        </nav>
```

For footer code:

```
<footer>
        <p>&copy; Company 2014</p>
      </footer>
    </div> <!-- /container -->


    <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript
    ================================================== -->
    <!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="<?= base_url(); ?>js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- IE10 viewport hack for Surface/desktop Windows 8 bug -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="<?= base_url(); ?>js/ie10-viewport-bug-workaround.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Check your console...you're getting this error; "Uncaught Error: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to include jquery.min.js before bootstrap.min.js

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?= base_url(); ?>js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Always add jquery.min.js at the top of all js